# How to deploy PyTorch in Centos6?

Tags: python, pytorch, centos6

Recently, I want to run some pytorch codes on centos6. However, no matter I perform either "pip install torch" or "conda install torch", the prompt shows:

```
>>>  import torch
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in
File "XXX/anaconda3/envs/XXX/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/init.py", line 56, in
from torch._C import *
ImportError: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by XXX/anaconda3/envs/XXX/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/_C.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)

My enviroment:
OS: CentOS release 6.7
How you installed PyTorch (conda, pip, source): pip & conda
Python version: 3.6.5
```

I tried mannually compiling glibc-2.19, but when I put the library path into LD_LIBRARY_PATH, I can't use commands like "ls", "make", etc. And I got "segment fault". I also tried just copying the *.so to the lib directory under the python virtual environment, no wonder, python crashed with "segment fault". I understand plenty of components rely on a specific glibc library. I just wonder how I can run pytorch on centos6 without switching to a new linux distribution.

PS: I need to deploy such python environments on the product environment, whose OS is centos6.

Comment: just fyi, centos 6 has reached its end of life (https://wiki.centos.org/About/Product)

Comment: if you can install docker or another container technology on the centos 6 machine, you can install a containerized pytorch environment.

Comment: In my case, product environment is unchangeable and I have no other options like reinstalling OS or making use of container technology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a tough one. You can either downgrade to a very old version of torch ( v0.3.1 as I remember was running ok on Centos 6.5 ), or upgrade to Centos 7. Having 2 version of glibc is hell.

If you really need Centos 6 to live with the latest version of torch, try installing glibc into non standard location and compiling both Python and pytorch from source.

**update**

You can't replace system's glibc and but you can install it somewhere else, like `/opt/myglibc`.
Pytorch stopped supporting Centos 6 since v0.4.1. So you will have to build it using gcc v5+ and linking it to your glibc version. Here are the [instructions](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch#from-source). But since you don't invoke pytorch directly, you need to build Python also. Then you can run your program by setting glibc path specifically for your program.

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/myglibc python my_program.py
```

Comment: So does it mean it should work if I mannually compile Python and PyTorch with the newer glibc on Centos 6? I can tolerate these mess as long as it works. The uncertainty is whether the source of the latest version of PyTorch requires high version of glibc.

Comment: According to [this penn state blog post](https://apus.psu.edu/1020/04/06/installing-pytorch-with-gpu-support-on-icds/) and [this pytorch discussion](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/minimum-glibc-version-for-installation-of-pytorch-when-installing-from-source/59956), it seems like the minimum glibc for compiling pytorch is 2.14. centos 6 probably will have 2.12. both of those links suggest compiling a more recent version of glibc (and putting it somewhere like `/opt/glibc`).